# Common return false function in JS on condition

Tags: javascript

I want a function which should return "`return false;`". which mean i should have a function called `escaping_function()` where ever i am calling this function it should do what "`return false;`" supposed to do.

example:

```
function my_function(){
   // my work..................
   // my work..................

   escaping_function();     // return false;

   //my work....................
   //my work....................
}
```

this function should work like how following function

```
function my_function(){
   // my work..................
   // my work..................

   return false;

   //my work....................
   //my work....................
}
```

both should act same. what should i do in `escaping_function();`.
help me out.

EDIT:-

```
function escaping_function(){
   // addEventListener() from button cancel and accept
   show two button pop up (alert box)
  if cancel pressed return false // should break host function

  else if accept pressed return true// should continue host function

  else continue showing alert box
}

function X(){
   //codes...............
   //codes...............
   //codes...............
   //codes...............

   escaping_function(); 

   //codes...............
   //codes...............
}

function Y(){
   //codes...............
   //codes...............
   //codes...............
   //codes...............

   escaping_function();

   //codes...............
   //codes...............
}
```

Note : `return escaping_function();` is breaking my function at any case which i don't want.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The nearest thing I can think of that would actually work would be to say `return escaping_function()` and then have `escaping_function()` return `false` itself. But why would you want to?

Comment: if i use `return escape_function()` and this function is having some line of code before `return false`, are those lines will be executed?

Comment: So you want the second `//my work`s to never be executed?

Comment: What is your actual use case? This sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: My plan is to break a function from another function on condition?

Comment: assume there is a two button called `button A` and` Button B`. When i press `button A` it should continue `function X()` and when i press `button B` it should break`function X()`. so link this with my question and answer or answer for this scenario.

Comment: @Vicky: Wait, so you actually don't want a `return` that exits the function, but you want to continue execution of the function later?

Comment: for ur note i am going to use this case in many places so that writing addEventListener() in many places is not so good... so common function is needed thats why i asked this question

Comment: @Vicky: Please [edit] your question to show how you would use `addEventListener` here. I don't get what you want. Do you already have actual code (not only pseudocode) and want to refactor that? If so, please post that.

Comment: edited check out @Bergi

Comment: You could use `long_jmp`. Oh wait, wrong language.

Comment: You could define `escaping_function` as a macro. Oh wait, wrong language.

Comment: @Vicky: Yes, that's what I guessed. But you want to use DOM events (where the buttons are clicked asynchronously), not the synchronous `window.alert`/`window.prompt` functions?

Comment: yes.. i have my own alert and prompt functions @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

My 2cts :

```
function my_function(){
    // my work..................
    // my work..................
    return escaping_function();     // return false;
    //my work....................
    //my work....................
}
```

Note: nothing will run after the `return`

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible. You cannot initiate a `return` from a different function than the current.

Btw, `return false;` is shorter than `escaping_function();` anyway :-)

Comment: assume there is a two button called `button A` and `Button B`. When i press `button A` it should continue `function X()` and when i press `button B` it should break `function X()`. so link this with my question and answer or answer for this scenario

Comment: for ur note i am going to use this case in many places so that writing addEventListener() in many places is not so good... so common function is needed thats why i asked this question

Comment: Writing `return false` in many places is not a problem. Or are you trying to do more than only that?

Comment: yes. absolutely.. and its like prompt alert box (customized alert box) which is having two button rite.. one is for cancel and another is for accept. and i need to use this prompt alert box in many places so that addEventListener() will not be efficient way to do (if nothing works i ll do this). so i need a common function which gets result of which button is been pressed and according to that it shoud break the function where i called the break function

Comment: Why would you need a `return`, though? Event callbacks are asynchronous anyway, so you cannot break/resume the function like that. You'd have that common function call at the end of your function body in any case.

Comment: i could't get what u r saying. please see my edited question... and make it clear...